# Как сделать подобный QListWidget PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qlistwidget

Пишу приложение. Весь день пытаюсь создать *QListWidget как на картинке, но не получается. Мне нужен QListWidget, содержащий в себе QPixmap, QLabel и QPushButton*. Только мне нужен динамический QListWidget, т.е. такой, чтобы пользователь мог сам по-своему желанию создавать новые его "странички, содержащие кнопку, надпись и фотографию". **Как я могу это осуществить?**
P.S. Кода не приложу, прилагать еще нечего(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Bitchdragon, вы же пишите: "Пишу приложение." Ну так покажите, что вы уже написали.

Comment: Просто там 1000 строк

Comment: А сократить, боюсь, никак

Comment: Bitchdragon, нет, ваш проект не нужен. Вы должны научится создавать  [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему. Просто покажите как вы пытаетесь создать QListWidget.

Comment: Блин, я удалил тот кусок кода

Comment: Перешел на другие дела в проекте пока что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам потребуется установить виджет для ячейки. см [setCellWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget)

Вот небольшой пример. `createCellWidget` формирует виджет, который затем устанавливается для ячейки с помощью `setCellWidget`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QFrame, QLabel, QPushButton, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def createCellWidget(self, pix, text, btn):
        layout = QGridLayout()
        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setLayout(layout)
        picture = QLabel()
        picture.setPixmap(pix)
        layout.addWidget(picture, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(text), 0, 1)
        button = QPushButton(btn)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda x: QMessageBox.information(self, 'clicked', 'button clicked'))
        layout.addWidget(button, 1, 1)
        return frame

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        table = QTableWidget(self)
        table.setColumnCount(2)
        table.setRowCount(100)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["one", "two"])
        for i in range(0, 100):
            pixmap = QPixmap('./my_pic.jpeg').scaled(32, 32)
            widget = self.createCellWidget(pixmap, f'text_{i}_0', f'button{i}_0')
            widget2 = self.createCellWidget(pixmap, f'text_{i}_1', f'button{i}_1')
            table.setCellWidget(i, 0, widget)
            table.setCellWidget(i, 1, widget2)
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        table.resizeRowsToContents()
        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Сергей!